# Hiding actionBar tabs with navigation mode adversely affecting fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, back-stack

I've got an activity with an actionbar, and actionbar tabs. When I choose an item from the contents of the tabs, I'm trying to replace the current fragment with a new one, add the transaction to the back stack, and hide the tabs.

I hide the tabs by changing the action bar navigation mode to standard.

The problem is that when I press the back button, I just get a blank view with the action bar (in standard mode).. The fragment transaction doesn't appear to be reversed.

If I don't hide the tabs by changing the navigation mode to standard, the transaction reversal works fine..

I've tried overriding the back press to change the navigation mode back to tabs, but it doesn't work.

Could someone tell me how they would achieve this?

Here is the code where the tabs get hidden and the fragment transaction takes place:

```
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        Fragment albumListFragment = new AlbumListFragment();
        albumListFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, albumListFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        ft.commit();
```

For clarity: I would expect that pressing back after this transaction has been committed, the tabs would come back into view with the previous fragment. At the moment after pressing back it's not showing the tabs OR the fragment.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this question is still relevant or not, but I seem to be having good luck hiding the tabs after the fragment transition.

From my ListFragment, I do a standard fragment transition very similar to how you're doing it in your code.

In my detail fragment, however, I hide the action bar in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

}
```

and show it again in my onPause method:

```
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

}
```